# What is the proper syntax for using wildcards with quotes in a SOLR query string?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to structure a query string in SOLR that will search a field for a term in quotation marks, but I want it to return substring matches. As an example:

`query: "his test"`

should return hits where it finds "his test", "this test", "his testing", but not "test his" for example. Does this make sense? What's the right way to construct the URL to hit /solr/select/ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

to accomplish your example, just turn on an english stemmer and stopword filter in your analysis chain. the stopword filter will leave a "hole" (position increment) which will be respected by phrase queries, so "his" and "this" both map to a hole.

the stemfilter will map testing and test to the same term.

Uwe says:
There is a simple Lucene-Rule: Whenever you need wildcards think about your analysis, you probably did something wrong :-)

Comment: Stemming might be a problem as we'd like to support other languages. Will stopwords only work on common words like "his" and "this"?
As for the need for wildcards, I'm just looking to have this match a substring, rather than an absolute term.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should looks in standard way, except you need wildcard in it.
If you want to add wildcard at the beginning of the term you would need [ReversedWildcardFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory) in the schema. Check out [schema example](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/conf/schema.xml?view=markup) (lines: 332-346)

For more info about how Solr with wildcards work read short article: [Wildcard queries and how Solr handles them](http://solr.pl/en/2010/12/20/wildcard-queries-and-how-solr-handles-them/)